# TSQL: Recursive Descent in JSON Path

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-json

I was hoping to take advantage of `$..` in `json_value()` function within TSQL queries using stored `json` documents. Unfortunately it doesn't work:

> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 2.

and according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), there was even no intention to:

> Path steps can contain the following elements and operators.
>
> Key names. For example, $.name and $."first name". If the key name starts with a dollar sign or contains special characters such as spaces, surround it with quotes.
>
> Array elements. For example, $.product[3]. Arrays are zero-based.
>
> The dot operator (.) indicates a member of an object. For example, in $.people[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).surname, surname is a child of people.

**Is there any other method, how to find the attribute `a` at any level(s) in structured `json` stored in a TSQL table column?**

For example, let's have `a` on arbitrary level in the `json` document:

`select json_value(json, '$..a') from data` would return both values (thus `1, 2`) for following values in `data.json` column:

first:

```
{
    "a": 1
}
```

second:

```
{
    "b": {
        "a": 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has indeed limited support for JSON expressions.

You could mix a recursive common table expression with the [openjson()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) function.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  json nvarchar(max)
);

insert into data (json) values
('{ "a": 1 }'),
('{ "b": { "a": 2 } }');
```

**Solution**

```
with rcte as
(
  select x.[key] as path,
         x.[key],
         x.[value],
         x.[type]
  from data d
  cross apply openjson(d.json, '$') x
    union all
  select r.[path] + '.' + rr.[key],
         rr.[key],
         rr.[value],
         rr.[type]
  from rcte r
  cross apply openjson(r.[value]) rr
  where r.[type] = 5 -- 5=object
)
select r.[key],
       r.[value],
       r.[path]
from rcte r
where r.[key] = 'a';
```

**Result**

```
key value path
--- ----- ----
a   1     a
a   2     b.a
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3a051631ca9ed587ab01139944ae6291) (with intermediate recursive common table expression results).

Comment: I've modified this so that the CTE also looks through arrays not just objects:
    where r.[type] in (4, 5) -- 4 = array, 5=object

btw works great. Thanks.